# Change/increase variable-value for load-url in onclick fuction

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a load more button on my page

```
<a class="btn btn-link border-top px-3 mt-5" role="button" id="reveal">Load more</a></p>
```

And an onclick function that loads content inside this div:

```
<div id="ajax-content" class="row m-0">

        </div>
```

The script works and loads more content every time I click the button:

```
<script>
$('#reveal').on('click', function() {
  $('#ajax-content').load('/wp-content/themes/template/ajax-news.php?offset=4');
  $('#ajax-content').attr('id', '#ajax-contented');
})
</script>
```

But I need the offset-variable to increase by 4 every time I click it, so the content that loads is not the same. Hope anyone can point me to the right direction to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you could use a `data` attribute on the `a` element which you increment by `4` on each successive click event:

```js
$('#reveal').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let offset = ($(this).data('offset') || 0) + 4;
  
  //$('#ajax-content').load('/wp-content/themes/heidner/ajax-aktuelt.php?offset=' + offset);
  $('#ajax-content').html(offset);
  $(this).data('offset', offset);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><a href="#" class="btn btn-link border-top px-3 mt-5" role="button" id="reveal">Last flere saker</a></p>
<div id="ajax-content" class="row m-0"></div>
```

This would also be possible with a global variable, but they are bad practice and should be avoided where possible.

In addition, note that changing `id` attributes at runtime is also not good practice. In this case it would stop the repeated clicks from updating the content. As such I removed that line.

Comment: Thanks! It works now. I needed to change the id attribute and load a new div within the page loaded to get it to work as I needed it to. But this was the solution for me. Thanks again, I do not have enough reputation to vote for the answer.